# How do I use PyCurl to send POST parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, post, pycurl

I'm using Python 3.7.  I'm trying to make a CURL POST request using PyCurl , but I'm having trouble figuring out how to assemble the form parameters.  I tried this

```
conn = pycurl.Curl()
if python3:
    conn.setopt(conn.CAINFO, certifi.where())
conn.setopt(conn.URL, str(SEARCH_URL))
send = [("MAX_FILE_SIZE", 10485760),
        ('url', image_url),
        ('search', 'search'),
        ('nsfwfilter', 'on'),]
conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, send)
conn.setopt(conn.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
conn.setopt(conn.USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0')
conn.setopt(conn.WRITEFUNCTION, returned_code.write)
conn.perform()
conn.close()
```

This dies with the error

```
  File "/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject_project/myproject/services/media_service.py", line 71, in doImageSearch
    conn.setopt(pycurl.HTTPPOST, send)
TypeError: unsupported second type in tuple
```

How do I properly format the parametesr?

Comment: What about `send = [("MAX_FILE_SIZE", "10485760"), ...`?

Comment: Yeah that was it.

Answer (score 1):

I posted my comment based on the error message and a hunch (I imagined that *MAX_FILE_SIZE* is one of the request's (*HTTP*) headers), and also didn't test it, but apparently I was correct. I tried looking for official documentation to support my statement, but I didn't have much luck. 
I searched [[PycURL]: Curl Object setopt(option, value) → None](http://pycurl.io/docs/latest/curlobject.html#pycurl.Curl.setopt), where I found this:

> It is possible to set integer options - and only them - that PycURL does not know about by using the numeric value of the option constant directly. For example, `pycurl.VERBOSE` has the value 42, and may be set as follows:
>
> ```py
> c.setopt(42, 1)
> ```

, but that's not what I'm expecting. Then, going further: [[Haxx.cURL]: CURLOPT_HTTPPOST explained](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPPOST.html), but it doesn't contain much useful info either. 
The only place that seems to be remotely related, is the mail thread: [[Haxx.cURL]: Difficulty uploading files via http](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/archive-2008-05/0025.html):

> I'm attempting to upload a file to a form that looks like this:
>
> ```
> <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="kget.php" method="post">
>  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
>  <input name="uploaded_file" type="file" />
>  <input type="submit" name="go" value="Upload" />
> </form>
> ```

So, making *MAX_FILE_SIZE*'s value a string, did the trick:

```py
send = [
    ("MAX_FILE_SIZE", "10485760"),  # @TODO - cfati: Notice the quotes
    ("url", image_url),
    ("search", "search"),
    ("nsfwfilter", "on"),
]
```